# How to use SQL join to pull out child id and name from closure table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have used SQL query to pull out the data

```
SELECT 
    tags.id, tags.tagname, tag_closure.decedent AS child_id 
FROM 
    tag_closure 
INNER JOIN 
    tags ON tags.id = tag_closure.ancestor 
WHERE 
    tag_closure.path_length = 1
```

The result I am getting is:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [tagname] => Life Science [child_id] => 2 )
Array ( [id] => 1 [tagname] => Life Science [child_id] => 6 )
Array ( [id] => 1 [tagname] => Life Science [child_id] => 13 )
```

I want to add extra key `child_name` within my results.

My tables are as

```
Table: tags_closure
|ancestor | decedent | path_length |


Table: tags
|id | tagname |
```

Please help me to implement the SQL JOIN statement.

Comment: `child_name` is not mentioned as a field in any of the two tables, or is it?

Comment: `child_name` would be the `tagname` for the `id` in tags table which is equal to `tag_closure.decedent` in the first select statement.

Comment: In that case, you will have to add another inner join to table tags setting the `ON` to the ID `tag_closure.decedent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured that out.
Thanks for comments.

The SQL query will be

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.tagname, t.decedent AS child_id, b.tagname AS child_name 
FROM 
    tag_closure t
INNER JOIN 
    tags a ON a.id = t.ancestor
INNER JOIN 
    tags b ON b.id = t.decedent
WHERE 
    t.path_length = 1
```